# Regular filepath for Qt resource

Tags: qt

I have an image file as a resource in a Qt project, and I have some library code that processes images, and takes the filename as an argument. What is the regular file path to my image file, or, how can I get it from Qt?

Comment: You imply that packed resources e.g. originally png files mapped to file system? No. Other than that the file is a file, the resource in executable is a resource inside executable file.

Comment: Have a look at http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/resources.html : every `.qrc` is parsed via the `rcc` command and all data is stored as `static const`

Comment: I think I figured that out - the "way to do it" is to save the Qt resource out to a regular (nominally, temporary) file, and pass that file along. Haven't gotten it working, but I don't think I have the resource properly added.